# Fully load all products using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have programmed a code in python to update prices of a web page (see code below). The code works without problems, the only issue is that the web shows only the first 10 products, and this is what the code detects. To fully load all the products, one must scroll down with the mouse so that they are loaded (see: https://supermercado.carrefour.com.ar/almacen.html?cat=6776).
The question is: is there a way to fully load all products using BeautifulSoup? I know this can be done by opening Chrome, loading the page, and scrolling down, but I'd like to have to avoid this to save time.
Thanks in advance for your help!

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from datetime import datetime

my_url='https://supermercado.carrefour.com.ar/almacen.html?cat=6776'

uClient=uReq(my_url)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup=soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers=page_soup.findAll('div', {'producto-info'})  

contain=containers[0]
container=containers[0]

filename="Carrefour.csv"
f=open(filename, "w")
headers="brand; precio_regular\n"
f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    precio_regular=container.findAll("p",{"class":"price 207 precio-regular-productos-destacados"})
    precio_regular=precio_regular[0].text.strip()

    brand=container.findAll("p",{"class":"brand truncate"})
    brand=brand[0].text.strip()

    f.write(brand + ";" + precio_regular + "\n")
        
print("Succesfully updated")    
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have to scroll down to reload implies that the additional records are loaded using Javascript. BeautifulSoup does not render Javascript, so you'd have to use something like Seleinum. However, if you use the developer tools in your browser, you can use the network tab to see what pages are being requested as you scroll.

It looks like it's hitting an api at the url below. You can use requests to get the next page and update the `p=<page>` parameter at the end of the query string.

`https://supermercado.carrefour.com.ar/infinitescroll/ajax/category/?id=6734&cat=6776&p=2`

It looks like the first page returns `{"status":"success","content":{"block":"","last":false}}` so I'd pull that info normally, but you can get the subsequent pages by parsing the api url.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

category = 6776

# Process first page
start = 'https://supermercado.carrefour.com.ar/almacen.html'
response = requests.get(start, params={'cat': category})
print(response.request.url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
containers = soup.findAll('div', {'producto-info'})
print(1, len(containers))

# Process additional pages
api_url = 'https://supermercado.carrefour.com.ar/infinitescroll/ajax/category/'
page = 2
while True:
    response = requests.get(api_url, params={
        'id': 6734,
        'cat': category,
        'p': page,
    })
    print(response.request.url)
    
    last = response.json()['content']['last']
    content = response.json()['content']['block']
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    containers = soup.findAll('div', {'producto-info'})
    print(page, len(containers))
    
    if last:
        break
    page += 1
```

As you can see from the output, this found a total of 24 items which matches what I see on the page.

```
https://supermercado.carrefour.com.ar/almacen.html?cat=6776
1 10
https://supermercado.carrefour.com.ar/infinitescroll/ajax/category/?id=6734&cat=6776&p=2
2 10
https://supermercado.carrefour.com.ar/infinitescroll/ajax/category/?id=6734&cat=6776&p=3
3 4
```